# Does mongoose createIndex: false mean indexes will be created in the background or not at all?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

> When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls
> createIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call
> createIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on
> the model when all the createIndex calls succeeded or when there was
> an error. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior
> be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant
> performance impact. Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex
> option of your schema to false, or globally on the connection by
> setting the option autoIndex to false.

The docs don't seem to address what happens when we set `autoIndex: false`. Will indexes be created in the background or do I have to write another program or script to make sure indexes are done properly in production?

Does this apply to all these scenarios the same?

- [default index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index) like `_id`
- indexes on `createdAt` like `someCollection.index({ createdAt: 1 })`
- indexes created inline like `new Schema({ someData: { type: String, default: '', index: true})`.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30616621/11312528) implies we can use `db.ensureIndex({ name: 1 }, { background: true });` But when I look for similar syntax in the mongoose docs I only found the following

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  registeredAt: { type: Date, index: true }
});

// [ [ { email: 1 }, { unique: true, background: true } ],
//   [ { registeredAt: 1 }, { background: true } ] ]
userSchema.indexes();
```

The commented out [section](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index) has `background: true` but it's not inline with the schema definition like `email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, background: true },`. I don't understand what they are trying to convey there.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31738744/11312528) says that `...an index build can happen in the "background"...` but I don't see this confirmed in the mongoose documentation. Maybe I missed it or maybe the issue is not understanding when to refer to the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/) over the [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual) when my application is using `mongoose` to handle all `mongodb` actions.

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Looking here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5342
It appears that options `{ background: true }` is the default when Mongoose creates indexes, and that you can override this.

As to your questions then:

> Does this apply to all these scenarios the same?
>
> - default index like _id

- the primary index would exist from inception of the collection

> - indexes on createdAt like someCollection.index({ createdAt: 1 })

- yes would apply, this index would not be created with autoIndex off

> - indexes created inline like new Schema({ someData: { type: String, default: '', index: true}).

- yes would apply, this index would not be created with autoIndex off